# How to get the distribution of $\frac{1}{n} \sum_i x_i^2$

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling

$X$ follows a normal distribution $X \text{~} N(\mu, \sigma^2) $.

And there are $n$ samples. Then what is the distribution of $$\frac{1}{n}  \sum_i x_i^2$$

I do understand $\frac{\sum_i x_i}{n} \text{~} N(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$, but don't know how to apply them here. Anybody who can help please?

Comment: Aside from a scaling factor, it will be [noncentral chi-squared](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution). Is this for homework?

Comment: Glen_b, I've been studying on my own. I don't know what a noncentral chi-squared dist is.. would you mind elaborating it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $X_1,...,X_n \sim \text{IID N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$ then this statistic has a [non-central chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution).  To see this, we observe that $X_1/\sigma,...,X_n/\sigma \sim \text{IID N}(\mu/\sigma, 1)$ so that:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \Big( \frac{X_i}{\sigma} \Big)^2 \sim \frac{\sigma^2}{n} \cdot \text{N-C Chi-squared} \Big( DF = n, NCP = \frac{n \mu^2}{\sigma^2} \Big).$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate how it becomes a non-central chisquare? Is there a way to understand it only by using basic mathematical stat?

Comment: Suppose $X\sim N(\mu,1)$. Then, $X^2$ is Non-central Chi-squared with 1 degree of freedom and $\mu^2$ as the non-centrality parameter. This can be shown, for example, using the method of moment generating function or transformation (CDF), involving messy algebra but still basic math stat. If $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $X^2$ is Non-central chi-square with 1 d.f. and $\mu^2/\sigma^2$ as the non-centrality parameter. This turns out to be a mixture of central chi-squares with mixing poisson probabilities.

Answer (score 2):

It is (nearly) a [noncentral chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution) *by definition*.

The difference is in a scaling factor.

---

#### Definitions

Both the central and noncentral chi-squared distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom are the distribution of the sum of the squares of $n$ independent distributed normal distributed variables.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i^2$$

- For the (central) **chi-squared distribution** you have $$X_i \sim N(0,1)$$.
- For the **noncentral chi-squared distribution** you have $$X_i \sim N(\mu_i,1)$$ and $\lambda = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \mu_i^2$ is the non-centrality parameter.

#### Transformation

For more general variables $X_i \sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$ you have that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} \sim \chi^2 \left( n,\sum_i (\mu_i / \sigma_i)^2 \right)$$

is a noncentral chi-squared distributed variable. So your case is a transformed version of it:

$$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2 = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_i^2}{\sigma_i^2}$$

---

#### The actual distribution function

Getting the actual expression for the distribution of the noncentral chi-squared distribution is not as easy as for the central chi-squared distribution (which can be derived easily using symmetry arguments). It will eventually be represented in terms of analytical functions (e.g. the modified Bessel function of the first kind).